# Is it secure to use used samsung SSDs?

Tags: ssd, security

Is it secure to buy and use used Samsung SSD after wiping it with Samsung Magician secure erase?

Is it possible for SSD still to be infected?

Comment: who is your adversary? just a random internet infection? or a nation-state? how high-profile a target are you?

Answer (score 0):

If you wipe it with the Samsung tool, that does the job of eliminating infections. This is the roughly same as full formatting a regular hard disk which removes infections and also root kit viruses.

Also check with the Samsung Magician (I have it here) to make sure the SSD is physically good.

A good quality (high end consumer) Samsung SSD is good for over 6 years of constant writes (Samsung reliability statistics) and so if 3 years old or less, the SSDs should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest concern when purchasing a used SSD should be the wear of the device: you do not want to deal with a broken drive or one that dies with your data on it. If you have fully wiped it, you can expect the chances of it having malware to be negligible.

Hard drives and SSDs should generally not be bought used, because you do not want them to fail on you. You can find very cheap high storage capacity SSDs available brand new, I can't imagine you're saving more than tens of dollars buying used, which just isn't worth it if you're concerned about security. Not to mention that the security risk is less of a concern than the risk of the drive failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nuanced answer, but essentially, yes it is almost certainly safe (from malware; I'd never buy a used disk; be sure to check the SMART stats).

Provided that your adversary is not a nation-state level actor or a powerful corporation, and you are not a highly-visible/desirable target, there is almost no likelihood that you have encountered malware that would go to the lengths necessary to persist across format/reinstall. This drops almost to zero if the system you use to wipe the disk is not the system that was "infected". These components not only store the malcode, but also cause it to be executed at boot, and use dirty tricks to hide the execution from the OS/user/security software. if they are not present, they cannot hide disks contents, and prevent them from being overwritten by the format.

I do encourage you to not only format/wipe the volume, but also to completely delete the partition table, and write a new one.

Malware that persists across formats usually uses other hardware to store its code, and that code has to be executed somehow. For instance [BIOS code](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2948092/hacking-teams-malware-uses-uefi-rootkit-to-survive-os-reinstalls.html) on the motherboard could be maliciously patched (though this almost certainly requires physical access), or it could be persisted in the [GPU](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/gpu-based-rootkit-and-keylogger-offer-superior-stealth-and-computing-power/).

so in sum, it is very difficult to persist malware over a format/reinstall, and that makes it quite difficult to deploy to victims. wipe the disk from another system using something like [dban](https://dban.org/), and there is very little cause for concern.